# Is it possible to create a generic Util Function to be used in Eval Page

Tags: asp.net, eval, nullable

I am currently binding a Nullable bit column to a listview control. When you declare a list view item I need to handle the case when the null value is used instead of just true or false.

```
<asp:Checkbox ID="Chk1" runat="server" 
    Checked='<%# HandleNullableBool(Eval("IsUsed")) %>' />
```

Then in the page I add a HandleNullableBool() function inside the ASPX page.

```
protected static bool HandleNullableBool(object value) 
{
    return (value == null) ? false : (bool)value;
}
```

This works fine but I need to use this in several pages so I tried creating a utility class with a static HandleNullableBool. But using it in the asp page does not work. Is there a way to do this in another class instead of the ASPX page?

```
<asp:Checkbox ID="Chk1" runat="server" 
    Checked='<%# Util.HandleNullableBool(Eval("IsUsed")) %>' />
```

Comment: You can also write `value ?? false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write

```
<asp:Checkbox ID="Chk1" runat="server" 
    Checked='<%# Eval("IsUsed") ?? false %>' />
```

To answer your question, you need to include the namespace that contains the class, like this: (at the top of the file)

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Your.Namespace.Here" %>
```

You can also do this in Web.config:

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Your.Namespace.Here" />
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: did not know you can do coallese in Eval expresssion. let me try